# Unable to activate Atom with Applescript

Tags: applescript, atom-editor

I'm trying to just switch to Atom and resize the window with basic Applescript:

```
tell application "Atom"
    activate
    set bounds of front window to {0, 495, 1680, 1050}
end tell
```

If Atom is not open, it launches but then the script throws an error and it doesn't resize the window:

```
An error of type -10810 has occurred.
```

If Atom is already running it just throws an error and doesn't even switch to Atom:

```
"Atom Helper got an error: Application isn’t running."
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh okay I just noticed that for some reason it automatically changes "Atom" to "Atom Helper" whenever I run the script. So changed it to reference the full path `"/Applications/Atom.app` instead and now it does exactly what I wanted.

```
tell application "/Applications/Atom.app"
    activate
    set bounds of front window to {0, 495, 1680, 1050}
end tell
```